# TypeScript - Shorthand way to assign all properties of one object to another

Tags: javascript, python, typescript

I have the following pattern in TypeScript (but also interested in just js)

```js
const configs = {
  "hello": {
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
    z: 1
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    const config = configs[id];
    this.x = config.x;
    this.y = config.y;
    this.z = config.z;
  }
}

const foo = new Foo("hello");
console.log(foo);
```

Is there a magic syntax for this? I seem to recall there was a way to do this in Python (although my google search was turning up empty)

(Edit: For clarity, I'd like to quickly assign all the properties of config as properties of Foo)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could take [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) with the wanted object.

```js
const configs = {
  "hello": {
    x: 1,
    y: 1,
    z: 1
  }
}

class Foo {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id;
    Object.assign(this, configs[id]);
  }
}

const foo = new Foo("hello");
console.log(foo);
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed.